# What does this mean? シャッター速度はB,１－１/１０００秒が切れます。

Tags: verbs

I was looking for some second-hand film camera on the internet. And there was a guy selling one with this condition:
シャッター速度はB,１－１/１０００秒が切れます。
What does "切れます" means in this case? It means the shutter works perfectly or doesn't work?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

**シャッターを切る** is a common set phrase that just means "to *release* the shutter." Don't ask me why 切る is used; maybe the third definition [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/58524/meaning/m0u/) is relevant. The sentence just says the shutter speed of the camera is "B, 1-1/1000秒".

Comment: B stands for "Bulb" (don't ask me why; it means the shutter opens when you press the release, and closes when you let go), and I think this must be saying that the shutter speeds are B, and the range from 1 sec to 1/1000 sec (but it would surely be more usual to write 「B、１～1/1000 秒」.

Comment: @BrianChandler: You used to squeeze a bulb of air to release the shutter, and the shutter would stay open as long as you squeezed the bulb.

Comment: Note: the shutter speed is “B, **1–1/1000**”. That first “1–” is important, since 1 second and 1/1000 second are the maximum and minimum shutter speeds when not in Bulb mode. @Brian That is what it says, isn’t it?

Comment: Oh so I failed to copy the `1-` part. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing the word 切れます could be concerning as it does mean "to break/to snap". But it can also be used to mark an achievement of sorts. Look at this similar example.

> １００メートル、１０秒切れる？
>
> 100 meters, will they break 10 seconds?

The sentence you have is probably describing the cutting edge of the shutter speed on the camera which seems to be 1 to 1/1000 seconds. (see what I did there?) So I think the camera is in good condition.

Answer (score 2):

シャッター速度はB,１－１/１０００秒が切れます。
"The shutter speed is B, can "cut" one in 1/1000th of a second."

Here, 切れます is in the potential form of 切る which means to cut. In this context though, we think about the shutter: The shutter "closes" its aperture as though they were several folds constricting, right? So, it is cutting 'light' as it closes.

So, a more "true-to-English" translation would be:
"The shutter speed is B, and is able to close once in 1/1000th of a second."

Pretty certain this is referring to the f-Stop setting for B (Bulb) on a camera, and 1/1000th of a second is a pretty fast shutter speed.

Comment: This isn’t quite correct. You’re missing that it says “1–1/1000”, that is “from one second to one thousandth of a second”. The camera’s shutter has two separate modes: B(ulb), where the shutter only closes when you release the press on the trigger; and timed shutter release, where the longest exposure is one second and the shortest is 1/1000 second. The ƒ-stop has nothing to do with it: that’s the camera’s aperture, which measures the size of the hole (the aperture) through which light is allowed to pass, not the length of time this hole is open.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right. My eyes kind of skipped 1-1/1000 and only saw the 1/1000. As far as cameras go, I might be somewhat uninformed. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

My take on the translation:

> when the camera mode is set to B (Bulb) you can use shutter settings from 1 second to 1/1000 second.

Yes, 切れます is the potential form of the verb. Bulb is usually used for long exposures, although 1 second is not very long and digital cameras can handle 1 second without the Bulb setting.

Another guess as to why "切" is that frames in film are visually-speaking "cut out" or carved from the negative once the shutter fires and advances.